# Tombstoning with MVVM and more than one page

Tags: windows-phone-7

Where can I find informatin about tombstononig with more that one page?
I`ve 2 pages every one with his own viewmodel, from page 1 nagite to page 2, If in this page ocurs tombstonig How can save and restore page1´s viewmodel?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. Save the state of page 1 in `OnNavigatedFrom` if the phone tombstones or navigates to page 2
2. Restore the state of page 1 in `OnNavigatedTo`.
3. Delete the state of page 1 if the user navigates backwards at page 1.